# try, throw , catch with 2-D array not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am still new to 2-D arrays but i am trying to get some exception handling to work with this:

```
const int employee = 3;   // number of employees
const int age = 4;      // number of ages
int employeesAge[employee][age] = { {50 , 0 , 45, 101}, {45, 6 ,7, 8} , {25 , 8,0, 35}}

for(int i =0; i < employeesAge[employee][age]; i++)
   if(employeesAge[employee][age] < 0 || employeesAge[employee][age] > 100)
   {
      try
       {
         throw employeesAge[employee][age];
       }
       catch(int param)
       {
          cout << "employee can't be under 0 age or over 100 to work here" << endl;
       }
    }
```

Now i am not even sure if what i did is even possible but this is the error i get:

```
uninitialized local variable 'employeesAge' used
```

If anyone can help that would be much appreciated. Now that i think about it i don't think the for statement i have is valid or necessary.

Comment: Is the error really about `employeeAge` (singular)? All I see in your code is `employeesAge` (plural). Which line is that error reported for?

Comment: And what do you expect to happen when you throw an int, and attempt to catch a string?

Comment: Also, this conditional is not what you meant to do: `i < employeesAge[employee][age]`

Comment: sorry i switch the param to int..no idea why i had string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `for(int i =0; i < employeesAge[employee][age]; i++)`, you are comparing integer `i` with `employeesAge[3][4]`, but those indices are out of bounds - the maximums in this case are `employeesAge[2][3]`. Also, your for loop really doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me - do you want 'foreach employee'? I suspect so - if that's the case, a closer solution is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < employee; i++)
{
    if(employeesAge[i][age] < 0 || employeesAge[i][age] > 100) {
    ...
}
```

But even that isn't quite right, now the `age` index is out of bounds for that array. I'm not sure what the logic is here - why would a single employee have multiple ages associated with them?  As your array is now, it looks like you have 3 employees, each with 4 ages. I'll take a guess, and say you have 3 GROUPS of employees, with 4 members per group. If that were the case, the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < employee; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < age; j++)
    {
        if(employeesAge[i][j] < 0 || employeesAge[i][j] > 100) {
            throw employeesAge[i][j];
        }
    }
```

}

...might make more sense, though I would definitely alter the index/array names to be more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see most of the mistakes i made and plan on taking the rest from here. Everything that you and everyone else pointed out though made me realize my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your indentation and braces (this isn't the error, but I want to point it out 'cause it could bite you in the butt and cause you a long painful debugging party):

```
for(int i =0; i < employeesAge[employee][age]; i++)
    if(employeesAge[employee][age] < 0 || employeesAge[employee][age] > 100) {
        try {
            throw employeesAge[employee][age];
        }
        catch(string param) {
            cout << "employee can't be under 0 age or over 100 to work here" << endl;
        }
    }
```

(the `for` loop has no opening or closing brace, which will surely lead to problems if you aren't ridiculously careful)

But more importantly you're looping wrong. You have `for(int i =0; i < employeesAge[employee][age]; i++)` but you never use `i`. This is wrong because 1) `employeesAge[employee][age]` is out of bounds (only indices `[0][0]` to `[employee - 1][age - 1]` are valid); and 2) because you never use `i` and keep using `employeesAge[employee][age]` which shows that you just keep checking the same value. Your compiler could be smart enough to know that `employeesAge[employee][age]` is out of bounds though and could be warning you.

Comment: i have reedited my code. so apparently it was my fault on the typo. it actually says "employeesAge". still no good.

Comment: @AjMunot: I've edited in response to your edits.